# Yocto Build Dependency on Debian Package

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I am working on migrating from Debian to Yocto. As a result, many of the proprietary packages I am writing recipes for have dependencies on Debian libraries which do not appear to be available directly in Yocto. This might be a rookie question, but I'm trying to figure out how to do this.

Below, I have one of my recipe for a Makefile C project that was generated with `recipetool create`:

```
# Recipe created by recipetool
# This is the basis of a recipe and may need further editing in order to be fully functional.
# (Feel free to remove these comments when editing.)

# WARNING: the following LICENSE and LIC_FILES_CHKSUM values are best guesses - it is
# your responsibility to verify that the values are complete and correct.
#
# The following license files were not able to be identified and are
# represented as "Unknown" below, you will need to check them yourself:
#   debian/copyright
LICENSE = "Unknown"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://debian/copyright;md5=some-hash"

SRC_URI = "git://git@my-project.git;protocol=ssh"

# Modify these as desired
PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "<...>"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
DEPENDS = "systemd"

# NOTE: this is a Makefile-only piece of software, so we cannot generate much of the
# recipe automatically - you will need to examine the Makefile yourself and ensure
# that the appropriate arguments are passed in.


do_compile () {
    oe_runmake my-project
}
```

As you can see, I have specified a dependency on `systemd`. However, the dependency I really think I need is the Debian package `libsystemd`.

Whenever I bitbake this recipe, I get the following:

```
NOTE: Executing Tasks
ERROR: <recipe-name> do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: <recipe-name> do_compile: Execution of '/home/mitch/bin/yocto/project-name/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/recipe-name/1.0+gitAUTOINC+...-r0/temp/run.do_compile.13271' failed with exit code 1:
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mitch/bin/yocto/project-name/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/recipe-name/1.0+gitAUTOINC+...-r0/git/src/core'
CC file-name.c
../file-name.c:6:10: fatal error: systemd/sd-daemon.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <systemd/sd-daemon.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:93: build/file-name.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mitch/bin/yocto/project-name/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/recipe-name/1.0+gitAUTOINC+...-r0/git/src/core'
make: *** [Makefile:72: some-recipe] Error 2
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/mitch/bin/yocto/project-name/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/recipe-name/1.0+gitAUTOINC+...-r0/temp/log.do_compile.13271
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 24 my-project
| make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mitch/bin/yocto/project-name/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/recipe-name/1.0+gitAUTOINC+...-r0/git/src/core'
| CC my-file.c
| ../my-file.c:6:10: fatal error: systemd/sd-daemon.h: No such file or directory
|     6 | #include <systemd/sd-daemon.h>
|       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| compilation terminated.
| make[1]: *** [Makefile:93: build/my-file.o] Error 1
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mitch/bin/yocto/project-name/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/recipe-name/1.0+gitAUTOINC+...-r0/git/src/core'
| make: *** [Makefile:72: my-project] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Execution of '/home/mitch/bin/yocto/project-name/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/recipe-name/1.0+gitAUTOINC+...-r0/temp/run.do_compile.13271' failed with exit code 1:
| make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mitch/bin/yocto/project-name/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/recipe-name/1.0+gitAUTOINC+...-r0/git/src/core'
| CC my-file.c
| ../my-file.c:6:10: fatal error: systemd/sd-daemon.h: No such file or directory
|     6 | #include <systemd/sd-daemon.h>
|       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| compilation terminated.
| make[1]: *** [Makefile:93: build/my-file.o] Error 1
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mitch/bin/yocto/project-name/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/recipe-name/1.0+gitAUTOINC+...-r0/git/src/core'
| make: *** [Makefile:72: my-recipe] Error 2
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| 
ERROR: Task (/home/mitch/bin/yocto/project-name/layers/meta-project/recipes-main/my-recipe/my-recipe_git.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2166 tasks of which 2163 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

To summarize, what this looks like is my project requires libraries provided by `systemd`. What am I missing here that would allow me to get this project to build? Is there a way to build it?

Comment: `Depends:` declares a run-time dependency for the built package. `Build-Depends:` indicates packages which must be installed at build time. I'm not familiar with Yocto but perhaps this can pe a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: @tripleee Can you clarify what you mean? DEPENDS declares a build time dependency, RDEPENDS declares a runtime dependency. Which are you suggesting I use in this case? I have tried both, but to my understanding, these are build time dependencies, right?

Comment: Sounds right; I was referring to the Debian control fields. So is there a reason you don't declare a dependency on `libsystemd-dev` or whatever the package with the `systemd` header fields is called in Yocto?

Comment: Well, honestly, I thought that systemd would provide it, but that doesn't seem to be the case. `libsystemd-dev` is not a recipe that is available to Yocto

Comment: `systemd-dev` provides these files, but it will be correctly loaded as you have `DEPENDS` on the main package `systemd`. Is it possible that the `Makefile` you are using somehow breaks the compilation? I mean that compile flags (especially the sysroot location) are lost? The recipe sysroot (when not only `systemd-dev` files are) is passed in the OpenEmbedded's `${CC}` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I guess I was overthinking this. Yocto uses your system to compile the project. So, all I needed to do was provide the systemd header files on my host machine. Since I am running Ubuntu, installing `libsystemd-dev` on my host fixed the issue. I *think* that the `DEPENDS` on systemd will still be required for running on the Yocto system.