# Build Dependency on Debian Package: Bitbake

Tags: linux, dependencies, yocto, bitbake

Trying to add the Debian package libsystemd. But I keep get the following error after, not sure how to solve this.

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'libsystemd' (but example.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it). Close matches:
  libteam
  systemd
  systemd RPROVIDES libsystemd
NOTE: Runtime target 'example' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['example', 'libsystemd']
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: [ 'example', 'libsystemd']
```

`fatal error: systemd/sd-daemon.h: No such file or directory | 16 | #include <systemd/sd-daemon.h>`

Related post: [Yocto Build Dependency on Debian Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68502105/yocto-build-dependency-on-debian-package)

example.bb

```
DESCRIPTION = "Example Utilities"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

inherit cmake systemd useradd

require common.inc

S = "${WORKDIR}/git/example-server"

DEPENDS = "simple-web-server boost sqlite3 libsystemd"
```

Comment: Have you added `systemd` to `DISTRO_FEATURES`?

Answer (score 0):

`systemd/sd-daemon.h` is provided by `systemd` recipe:

In `image` (`${D}`) folder there is:

```
$ tree usr/include/
usr/include/
├── libudev.h
└── systemd
    ├── sd-bus.h
    ├── sd-bus-protocol.h
    ├── sd-bus-vtable.h
    ├── _sd-common.h
    ├── sd-daemon.h    <======(Header file you are looking for)
    ├── sd-device.h
    ├── sd-event.h
    ├── sd-hwdb.h
    ├── sd-id128.h
    ├── sd-journal.h
    ├── sd-login.h
    └── sd-messages.h
```

Also, `libsystemd` is provided by `systemd` package, so change `DEPENDS` to:

```
DEPENDS = "simple-web-server boost sqlite3 systemd"
#                                           ^
#                                           |
# ===========================================
```